# New to npm get SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: laravel, vue.js, babeljs, core-ui

Edit : I've change my package.json according to the progress of my research it seems to be related to babel, I keep looking. However, I wanted to change the package.json that I present to you from which I will work from now on and try to find the right dependencies.

I am currently facing a problem to integrate the coreui template into laravel 5.7.

I get this error :

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

It happened in the router file. It crashes at the component import level.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

// Containers
const DefaultContainer = () =>/* HERE */ import('@/containers/DefaultContainer')
```

I am new to npm and really don't know how to solve that. So any help will be  highly appreciated.

Here is my package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "install": "^0.12.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.0.4", 
    "@coreui/icons": "^0.3.0",
    "@coreui/vue": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
}
```

}

Comment: try to use `npm i @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.47` and use `require`

Comment: in the root of your project open CLI window and run `npm i @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.47` and use `require` in your code

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your solution but it gave me the following error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@xxxxx'  If I change the relative path to absolute path it will commit me to change all the paths of components that also use components.
This template is really well done from a front only point of view. The use of vuejs is excellent that's why I would like to not modify the original files and instead focus on the dependencies needed to compile a project in Laravel and start working

Comment: I edited my question hoping that it would make it more workable.

Comment: did you try to delete node_modules folder and to rerun `npm i`?

Comment: Yes and also try to change `const DefaultContainer import('@/containers/DefaultContainer')` in `import DefaultContainer from  '@/containers/DefaultContainer'` and I get a bunch of error like this `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips' in '/var/www/html/suivi-vente-2/blog/resources/js/coreui/views/charts'`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I just create a file `.babelrc` on the root of the project and add

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

Now I get an other issue that I ask in other question.
Thank you Boussadjra Brahim for your help :)